# get array of different values of the same element using protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, promise, protractor

i'm trying to test an application that displays graphs using rickshaw and d3. tests are implemented using protractor and jasmine. as a side note, i believe the question is not really specific to this use case and is more generic.

so, the test is supposed to hover a mouse over a graph and collect the text that is shown for each point ([example](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/lines.html)). this array is then to be matched against a given array.

i hope this pseudocode illustrates the problem:

```
var graph = ... //
var promises = [];
var promise = graphElement.getSize().then(function(size){
    _.times(size, function(i) {
        moveMouse(i, 0); // move mouse to i-th pixel
        promises.push(graph.element(by.css('.hover-text')).getText());
    });
    return promises;
});

promise.magicallyWaitForAllOfThem();

_.each(promises, function(textPromise){
    expect(textPromise).toBe('something');
});
```

so, the problem is that since i need the size to resolve first, i don't have a way to wait for all promises to resolve and return an array of text promises that can later be used with expect().

EDIT: explicitly mentioned protractor/jasmine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

can't you simply use selenium webdriver's `promise.all`?

```
var graph = ... //
var webdriver = require("selenium-webdriver");

graphElement.getSize().then(function(size){
    var promises = [];
    _.times(size, function(i) {
        moveMouse(i, 0); // move mouse to i-th pixel
        promises.push(graph.element(by.css('.hover-text')).getText());
    });
    return webdriver.promise.all(promises);
}).then(function(promiseResultArray){
    _.each(promiseResultArray, function(textPromise){
        expect(textPromise).toBe('something');
    });
});
```

**cleaner way:**

declare it:

```
collectHoverText: function(elem) {
  var strings = [];
  var promises = [];

  return elem.getSize().then(function(size) {
    _.times(0/*logic for number of steps*/, function(i) {
      var x = 0; // logic for step
      browser.actions().mouseMove(elem, {x: x, y: 0}).perform();
      promises.push(elem.element(by.css('.hover-text')).getText().then(function(text) {
        strings.push(text);
      }));
    });

    return protractor.promise.all(promises).then(function() {
      return _.uniq(strings);
    });
  });
```

and use it:

```
var hoverTextPromise = collectHoverText(graph);
expect(hoverTextPromise).toContain('value'); // resolved array here
```

Comment: is it any different from protractor.promise.all?

Comment: can it be achieved without the callback?

Comment: you mean without `then`? you are doing an async call, you are going to need a callback